# Display data fetched from remote PHP (mysql) in html table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I have a PHP page displaying data from a mysql database, based on a dropdown list selection, also from a mysql database. This obviously makes use of a JavaScript.

The PHP and mysql integration is working perfectly however I need to change the way the data is displayed.

Currently the returned mysql data is displaying in one table cell, I want each returned mysql field to be displayed in its own table cell.

I have added a photo of the output, I want it to display in each table cell, not in one.

I have attached the code from both my PHP file and the PHP file querying the database.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'unilever_root', 'Unilever2011');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("unilever_unilever", $con);     

$skusql="SELECT packcode from skudata"; 
$resultsku=mysql_query($skusql); 

$optionssku=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsku)) 
{ 
    $sku=$row["packcode"]; 
    $optionssku.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sku\">".$sku; 
} 

?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>SKU</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>SU</td>
    <td>Points</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Grouping</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <OPTION VALUE=0>
            <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**getdata page**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'password');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("unilever_unilever", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
    echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SellingUnits'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EOTTPoints'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Grouping'] . "</td>";
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: hi i had to retag `java` into `javascript`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is not meant to be a "write  my code for me" site - if that's what you are looking for, you should probably hire an expert to do it for you. If you have a *specific* technical question arising of your working on the issue, feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Pekka, I am 100% with you in that its not a write it for me site. I have written this code in the question based on examples I found on the net. it is working well I am just having one issue which I cant get working, hence my question. I have done the research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you've used two ideas that don't quite work together. This line: `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` is setting the content of the tag with id "txtHint" to what your php script returns. This means that when your php returns, for example: 
`<td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td>`
then your page ends up with:

```
<div id="txtHint">
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
</div>
```

Do you see what's happening here? You aren't adding more cells to the existing row, you're creating another table within the cell you already have (and a bad one at that, with no `<table>` or `<tr>` tags...).

To get around this, change the element with id "txtHint" to the `<tr>` tag for the row you are editing, and update the php to return the first cell of that row as well, eg:

HTML:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>SKU</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>SU</td>
        <td>Points</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Grouping</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="txtHint">
            <td>
                <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <OPTION VALUE=0>
                <?=$optionssku?> 
                </SELECT> 
            </td>
        <td colspan="5">SKU Details will be seen here</td>
    </tr>
```

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    echo "<td><select name='users' onchange='showUser(this.value)'><OPTION VALUE=0>"; 
    echo $optionssku; //Not sure where this variable comes from, so I'll leave getting it from wherever necessary to you
    echo "</SELECT></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SellingUnits'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EOTTPoints'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Grouping'] . "</td>";
}
```

(code not tested, but it'll be something like this).

There are certainly other methods to get around this problem, almost certainly better ones, but this is the first idea that came to me.